# How does ActivityContext, LocationReferenceEnvironment, Arguments and Variables work in WF4?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I understand that flow control and context are separated on WF4 but I'm asking you how can I control the context of a given workflow.

`WorkflowApplication` have a `HostEnvironment` property which, accordingly to documentation *gets or sets the root environment for the workflow instance’s arguments and variables*.

What's the difference between `LocationReferenceEnvironment` and the `ActivityContext` itself? Who creates and controls the context? As I understand it each activity has its own context but not all activities have variables, for example.

I want the maximum control over the context of a given workflow but I'm having trouble understanding the inner workings of all this stuff. Can someone explain it to me and/or pointing me some good articles preferably from programming's point of view. Unfortunately MSDN , and more specifically .NET Framework Class Library, are scarce on good WF4 documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any documentation on the internals here. Not sure if it would do you a lot of good, most if not all of this stuff is internal to WF4 and can't be changed even if you wanted to.

Basically a location reference is a place to store data, something exposed by a variable in your workflow. By default you can only add variables to composite activities. There is no technical reason here it's just that a variable is used to share data between multiple activities so adding them to an activity that doesn't have children, or only a single, doesn't buy you anything. That said you are free to do so in your own activities if you want to.

What are you trying to accomplish that you need maximum control over the activity context?

**Update:** Not sure if this helps but this is how you can create VB expressions in code:

```
var wf = new Sequence()
{
    Variables =
    {
        new Variable<string>("var1", "Some value"),
        new Variable<int>("var2", c=> Environment.TickCount),
    },
    Activities =
    {
        new WriteLine() {
            Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"String value: \" & var1 ")
        },
        new WriteLine() {
            Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"Int value: \" & var2 ")
        }

    }
};

WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf);
```

Comment: The problem is bigger than this. I'm writing an Workflow Definition API and I want to use the WF4/CLR as the engine. The translation from the API to WF4 is proving to be impossible with respect to variables and arguments. I've already described my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593474/workflow-definition-api-on-top-of-wf4). I've decided to post a new question in search for some valuable information because nobody seems to be able to help me in my original (and bigger) problem. Maybe you can help me out on that :) I'm struggling with this for weeks.

Comment: Awesome! This is a all new way to look at the problem. One more time VisualBasicValue is not extensively documented but I'll definitely take a look into it. Just take this questions out of my way please: what VisualBasicValue does it access variables through their name right? Why are you using the ActivityContext on "var2" and not on "var1"? I've tried to remove that parameter and it worked the same way.

Comment: Just one more question. This is the normal way: `Text = new InArgument<string>(c => String.Format("String value: {0}", var1.Get(c)))`. Why VisualBasicValue doesn't need the context? Where is it getting the references?

Comment: The difference between var1 and var2 is just that var1 is fixed value known in advance while var2 is a lambda and loads the value when requested. In neither case am I using the context. The VisualBasicValue parse the expression and evaluated any variables in there, I assume it uses the context internally to do so. And yes, it use the variable names not a reference.

Comment: Is it possible to use this custom classes? Access those custom classes' properties. It seems that it only supports value types, am I right?

Comment: Variables can contain any valid .NET type. They are not restricted to value types.

Comment: @Maurice It doesn't seem straighforward to use custom classes, at least the way that I'm think of using them. I've opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802497/visualbasicvaluet-access-custom-classes-and-its-methods-properties) regarding that topic. Can you please check it? You seem one of the few people around able to answer it. Thanks in advanced.